# Extract vmlinux from vmlinuz or bzImage

Tags: bash, linux-kernel, kernel

I want to generate System.map from vmlinuz,cause most of machines don't have the file System.map.In fact,vmlinuz are compressed to vmlinuz or bzImage.

It's any tool or script can do this?

I tried:

```
dd if=/boot/vmlinuz skip=`grep -a -b -o -m 1 -e $'\x1f\x8b\x08\x00' /boot/vmlinuz | cut -d: -f 1` bs=1 | zcat > /tmp/vmlinux
```

It was failed:

```
zcat: stdin: not in gzip format
32769+0 records in
32768+0 records out
```

Comment: Are you sure? There are no symbols in extracted files ;-(

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/298826/how-do-i-uncompress-vmlinuz-to-vmlinux

Answer (score 23, accepted):

To extract the uncompressed kernel from the kernel image, you can use the `extract-vmlinux` script from the `scripts` directory in the kernel tree (available at least in kernel version 3.5) (if you get an error like

> mktemp: Cannot create temp file /tmp/vmlinux-XXX: Invalid argument

you need to replace `$(mktemp /tmp/vmlinux-XXX)` by `$(mktemp /tmp/vmlinux-XXXXXX)` in the script). The command is `/path/to/kernel/tree/scripts/extract-vmlinux <kernel image> >vmlinux`.

If the extracted kernel binary contains symbol information, you should¹ be able to create the `System.map` file using the `mksysmap` script from the same subdirectory. The command here is `NM=nm /path/to/kernel/tree/scripts/mksysmap vmlinux System.map`.

¹ The kernel images shipped with my distribution seem to be stripped, so the script was not able to get the symbols.

Comment: thanks for your help!!I got the script from 3.5.2 and the result is [root@lwq2 test]# ./extract-vmlinux.sh vmlinuz 
extract-vmlinux.sh: Cannot find vmlinux.

Comment: Hm, I actually had the same problem first, the cause was that the script failed to create a needed temporary file /tmp/vmlinux-XXX (in my case, I needed to change that to /tmp/vmlinux-XXXXXX to get it working, the needed number of X'es should be mentioned in the manual page for mktemp). The extract-vmlinux script from version 3.5.2 also uses three X'es instead of six, so this could probably be the problem...

Comment: For ARM it fails with "extract-vmlinux: Cannot find vmlinux": https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/352215/how-do-i-extract-vmlinux-from-an-arm-image

Comment: The 'kernel tree" you mean the kernel source tree?

Comment: Yes, the kernel tree that is available from https://www.kernel.org/.

Answer (score 2):

As [Abrixas2 wrote](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12002789/4518341), you will need a kernel image with symbol information in order to create System.map files and a packed vmlinuz image is not likely to have symbols in it. I can, however, verify that the script in your original post works with '-e' replaced with '-P' and '$' dropped, i.e.,

```
$ dd if=vmlinuz-3.8.0-19-generic skip=`grep -a -b -o -m 1 -P '\x1f\x8b\x08\x00' vmlinuz-3.8.0-19-generic | cut -d: -f 1` bs=1 | zcat > /tmp/vmlinux
gzip: stdin: decompression OK, trailing garbage ignored
```

Comment: This does not appear to work with the latest version of grep.

Comment: It works for me. Excellent. Saved lot of my time. No need to download the source or manual steps to decompress.

Answer (score 1):

try this :

```
dd if=vmlinuz bs=1 skip=24584 | zcat > vmlinux
```

with

```
24584 = 24576 + 8
```

when

```
od -A d -t x1 vmlinuz | grep '1f 8b 08 00'
```

gives

```
....... 0  1  2  3  .  .  .  .  8  
0024576 24 26 27 00 ae 21 16 00 1f 8b 08 00 7f 2f 6b 45
```

enjoy !

Comment: This is confusing because it's in reverse order. Most people reading this probably aren't going to have that exact "skip" value (right?) so it doesn't make sense to just *give* the command first. It'd be clearer if you explained it step-by-step.

Answer (score 0):

I'm on ubuntu linux.
you can change `$'\037\213\010\000'` to `"$(echo '\037\213\010\000')"` in sh

```
bash$ N=$(grep -abo -m1  $'\037\213\010\000' vmlinuz-4.13.0-37-generic | awk -F: '{print $1+1}') && 
tail -c +$N vmlinuz-4.13.0-37-generic | gzip -d > /tmp/vmlinuz
```

Comment: Careful, `$'\000'` actually terminates the string in Bash, at least on 5.0.