# crash dump on ubuntu: vmlinuz or crash file not a supported file format

Tags: c, linux, ubuntu, coredump

I am trying to analyze crash dump on my ubuntu machine using `crash` utility as below

```
$ sudo crash /boot/System.map-3.2.0-23-generic-pae /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-23-generic-pae _usr_sbin_ietd.0.crash
```

But it returns error as

```
crash: /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-23-generic-pae: not a supported file format
```

As per crash utility syntax I have provided arguments correctly

```
crash <system-map-file> <vmlinux-file> coredump
```

What am I doing wrong in here?

**UPDATE:**

vmlinuz file in boot dir appears to be bzimage compressed

```
$ file vmlinuz-3.2.0-23-generic-pae 
vmlinuz-3.2.0-23-generic-pae: Linux kernel x86 boot executable bzImage, version 3.2.0-23-generic-pae (buildd@palmer) #36-Ubuntu SMP Tue Apr 10 , RO-rootFS, swap_dev 0x4, Normal VGA
$
```

Comment: `vmlinuz` is a compressed image. Perhaps `crash` requires uncompressed (`vmlinux`). You could try `gunzip /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-23-generic-pae` (save the original first, and make sure there's room for the uncompressed image in the partition).

Comment: ok it is compressed but in bzImage format

Comment: OK same idea. I just had the wrong decompression program. You might find [this question/answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12002315/extract-vmlinux-from-vmlinuz-or-bzimage) helpful.

Comment: now I getting same error for crash file. `crash: /var/crash/_usr_sbin_ietd.0.crash: not a supported file format`

Comment: Another open question is how the kernel was built. It says in the documentation for `crash` (under [prerequisites](http://people.redhat.com/anderson/crash_whitepaper/#PREREQUISITES)): *A `vmlinux` kernel object file, often referred to as the namelist in this document, which **must have been built with the `-g C` flag** so that it will contain the debug data required for symbolic debugging.* Is that the case here?

Comment: I used `apport-unpack` to extract core dump file from crash report. Added some info below. I guess I didnt had `-g` flag and hence there is no debugging info in it

Comment: @lurker You can add your comment as answer. I will accept it

Answer (score 8):

As per @lurker's comments 
vmlinuz is compressed and can be uncompressed using below command (from [Extract vmlinux from vmlinuz or bzImage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12002315/extract-vmlinux-from-vmlinuz-or-bzimage))

```
$ sudo dd if=vmlinuz-3.2.0-23-generic-pae skip=`grep -a -b -o -m 1 -P '\x1f\x8b\x08\x00' vmlinuz-3.2.0-23-generic-pae| cut -d: -f 1` bs=1 | zcat > /tmp/vmlinux
    4998324+0 records in
    4998324+0 records out
    4998324 bytes (5.0 MB) copied, 201.859 s, 24.8 kB/s

    gzip: stdin: decompression OK, trailing garbage ignored
```

Now for error

crash: /var/crash/_usr_sbin_ietd.0.crash: not a supported file format

we also need to extract core dump file from crash report using `apport-unpack` as below ([from here](https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+question/240706))

```
@ubuntu:/tmp$ sudo apport-unpack 
Usage: /usr/bin/apport-unpack <report> <target directory>

@ubuntu:/tmp$ sudo apport-unpack /var/crash/_usr_sbin_ietd.0.crash /var/crash/
ERROR: Destination directory exists and is not empty.
@ubuntu:/tmp$ 

@ubuntu:/tmp$ sudo mkdir coretest

@ubuntu:/tmp$ sudo apport-unpack /var/crash/_usr_sbin_ietd.0.crash /tmp/coretest/
@ubuntu:/tmp$ cd coretest/
@ubuntu:/tmp/coretest$ 

@ubuntu:/tmp/coretest$ ls
Architecture  Date           ExecutablePath       ProblemType  ProcCwd      ProcMaps    Signal  UserGroups
CoreDump      DistroRelease  ExecutableTimestamp  ProcCmdline  ProcEnviron  ProcStatus  Uname

@ubuntu:/tmp/coretest$ ls -lt
total 384
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root      4 May 29 00:13 Architecture
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     24 May 29 00:13 Date
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     12 May 29 00:13 DistroRelease
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     10 May 29 00:13 ExecutableTimestamp
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 339968 May 29 00:13 CoreDump
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root      5 May 29 00:13 ProblemType
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     66 May 29 00:13 ProcEnviron
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    969 May 29 00:13 ProcMaps
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    737 May 29 00:13 ProcStatus
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root      2 May 29 00:13 Signal
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     31 May 29 00:13 Uname
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     14 May 29 00:13 ExecutablePath
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     14 May 29 00:13 ProcCmdline
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root      1 May 29 00:13 ProcCwd
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root      0 May 29 00:13 UserGroups
@ubuntu:/tmp/coretest$ cd CoreDump
bash: cd: CoreDump: Not a directory
@ubuntu:/tmp/coretest$ sudo crash /tmp/vmlinux /boot/System.map-3.2.0-23-generic-pae /tmp/coretest/CoreDump 

crash 6.1.6
Copyright (C) 2002-2013  Red Hat, Inc.
Copyright (C) 2004, 2005, 2006, 2010  IBM Corporation
Copyright (C) 1999-2006  Hewlett-Packard Co
Copyright (C) 2005, 2006, 2011, 2012  Fujitsu Limited
Copyright (C) 2006, 2007  VA Linux Systems Japan K.K.
Copyright (C) 2005, 2011  NEC Corporation
Copyright (C) 1999, 2002, 2007  Silicon Graphics, Inc.
Copyright (C) 1999, 2000, 2001, 2002  Mission Critical Linux, Inc.
This program is free software, covered by the GNU General Public License,
and you are welcome to change it and/or distribute copies of it under
certain conditions.  Enter "help copying" to see the conditions.
This program has absolutely no warranty.  Enter "help warranty" for details.

GNU gdb (GDB) 7.3.1
Copyright (C) 2011 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "i686-pc-linux-gnu"...

crash: /tmp/vmlinux: no debugging data available

@ubuntu:/tmp/coretest$
```

For "No debugging data available", need some debuginfo packages (programname-dbg or progname-dbgsym) installed as per [this link](http://www.dedoimedo.com/computers/crash.html#mozTocId641165) and this [one](http://sysprogs.com/VisualKernel/tutorials/setup/ubuntu/)

Steps for downloading debuginfo packages for kernel are mentioned in question https://askubuntu.com/questions/197016/how-to-install-a-package-that-contains-ubuntu-kernel-debug-symbols

However, step of adding GPG key(as below) is crucial for the download to work

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys ECDCAD72428D7C01
```

You should receive message as

> public key "Ubuntu Debug Symbol Archive Automatic Signing Key
>   " imported

and not "not changed" status. If it says "not changed" in this step then You wont be able to download debuginfo package.

In that case try importing GPG key using http 80 port as([here](https://superuser.com/questions/620765/sudo-apt-key-adv-keyserver-keyserver-ubuntu-com-recv-7f0ceb10-command-return))

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv 7F0CEB10
```

Comment: Glad you got all the pieces sorted! You can accept your own answer on SO. :)

Comment: @lurker working now I downloaded debuginfo package as well. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

*vmlinuz* is a compressed file, but crash requires an uncompressed file *vmlinux*, which is compiled with -g option.
Make sure your kernel is compiled with -g option, and then you can get an uncompressed *vmlinux* file from compressed *vmlinuz*, using the method as follows:
1. `od -t x1 -A d vmlinuz | grep "1f 8b 08"`
    e.g. you get an output:
    0018352 ac fe ff ff **1f 8b 08** 00 00 00 00 00 02 03 ec fd
2. Compute the offset to "1f 8b 08": 0018352 + 4 = 0018356.
3. Use dd to uncompress your vmlinuz:
    `dd if=vmlinuz bs=1 skip=18356 | zcat > vmlinux`
Now you get the uncompressed kernel file vmlinux. Congratulations!