# analyzing crash dumps with debian kernel packages

Tags: linux-kernel, debian, crash-dumps

I’m trying to analyze a Linux kernel crash dump. The kernel was built out of 4.4.77 tree with some custom packages on top of that. The command to build the kernel was `make-kpkg kernel_image debug_image`, producing in 2 different debian packages. The idea is that the first package runs in production, the second package can be utilized for debugging if a problem is detected. So the “kernel_image” package was installed, configured for collecting crashes per [instructions](https://superuser.com/questions/280767/how-can-i-enable-kernel-crash-dumps-in-debian), ran, crashed and wrote a crash dump file.

I am using `crash` utility to analyze the dump. Running

```
crash vmlinux file.dump
```

for vmlinux file uncompressed per [instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12002315/extract-vmlinux-from-vmlinuz-or-bzimage) outputs

```
crash: vmlinux: no .gnu_debuglink section
crash: vmlinux: no debugging data available
```

Installing the “debug_image” package does not change that.

I noticed that the “debug-image” package contains its own vmlinux file; it is placed in /usr/lib/debug/lib/modules/4.4.77+/ upon installation. Running

```
crash /usr/lib/debug/lib/modules/4.4.77+/vmlinux file.dump
```

Outputs

```
WARNING: kernels compiled by different gcc versions:
  /usr/lib/debug/lib/modules/4.4.77+/vmlinux: (unknown)
  dump.201802261029 kernel: 4.8.4

WARNING: kernel version inconsistency between vmlinux and dumpfile

crash: incompatible arguments: 
   /usr/lib/debug/lib/modules/4.4.77+/vmlinux is not SMP -- dump.201802261029 is SMP
```

What am I missing? Is it possible to analyze the the dump from “kernel_image” utilizing the info available in “debug_image” package?

*Update*: Apparently the system had a `makedumpfile` binary being too old for 4.4 kernels. At some point in the past the system's kernel was updated from 3.something to 4.4 but all user-mode binaries stayed as they were. That somehow caused an invalid crash dump. I could not just `apt-get install` newer `makedumpfile` (part of `kdump-tools` package) due to binary incompatibilities. The problem has been resolved after I re-built `makedumpfile` binary v 5.9 in the same dev environment as the one used to build user-mode applications for the system. Summarizing, **pointing `crash` to `vmlinux` file from "debug-image" package worked for me at the end**.

Comment: Well, error message clearly states that your crash dump is from kernel of version `4.8.4` and you use debug info from `4.4.77` version. In your place I would try to install install `kernel-debuginfo-4.8.4` package and then try to find out how it could be that your production kernel was built out of `4.4.77` tree and its crash dump is of `4.8.4` version

Comment: My interpretation is that "4.8.4" is the gcc version rather than the kernel version.

Comment: yes, you are correct, I've missed that

Comment: BTW, which `Crash` utility version do you use? Its older versions contained a bug that prevented work with linux 4.0 crash dumps. And the error message was exactly like yours: https://bugs.archlinux.org/task/44925

Comment: I am using a freshly-installed crash 7.1.7; I think it has a fix for that bug.