# How to get kernel version without running it (Get ARM kernel version on an AMD64 Linux)

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, embedded-linux

I need to know the version of a kernel file without running it. Therefore, the following questions arise in this realm:

1. Is it possible to get the kernel version in the u-boot environment? I mean before running the kernel I want to get the version of my kernel file.
2. Suppose I am running ubuntu on my amd64 processor and I have a zImage file which is cross compiled for ARM processor. Therefore I can not run this zImage file on amd64. *Then how can I get version of this zImage file without running it on an ARM processor?* I checked out `uname` manual but it does not accept a file as argument. I also issued `readelf -V` on a `vmlinux` kernel file, but it was an unsuccessful attempt.

Comment: Stack Overflow is for programming questions. You might try asking on [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) or [Super User](https://superuser.com/) instead.

Comment: Of course, the simplest thing would be to include the version number in the image's file name when you create it.  That's what many distributions do.

Comment: @NateEldredge consider the case which I have a prebuilt kernel and I do not know the version.

Comment: You can [extract](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12002315/extract-vmlinux-from-vmlinuz-or-bzimage) the ELF image from the zImage and then use something like `strings` or other ELF tools to read it.  But I don't think you'll have those tools available in a bootloader.

Comment: 1.Yes, it's possible as long as you know the method how kernel image (e.g. *bzImage* for x86) is packed. 2. See 1.